# "Зависание" программы

Tags: java, сериализация

```
String ucarts = String.valueOf(user.getNumber());
System.out.println("0");
users.add(user);
System.out.println("1");
serData(ucarts, users);
System.out.println("2");
```

В консоли пишет 1, и всё. Дальше программа ничего не выводит и не завершается.
Причем когда я насильно ее завершаю, файл появляется. Если в тексте нет ничего подозрительного, хотя бы скажите, с чем это может быть связано.

*P.S. `user.getNumber` и остальное не null.*

Если убираю `system.exit()`, ничего не происходит, извиняюсь, я начинающий...

Comment: Что такое serData? У вас, судя по всему, бесконечный цикл или ожидание в этом вызове.

Comment: serData - функция, отправляющая данные в файл. А бесконечных циклов внутри нету... Копировал её у же с работоспособного кода.

Comment:     try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file_name+".bank");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(obj);
            fileOut.close();
            out.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found");
            System.exit(1);
        }catch(java.io.IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
            System.exit(2);
        }
вот serData.

Comment: Очевидно, программа "зависает" в методе serData - можете код этого метода приложить?

Comment: Выше уже написал.

Comment: В случае Exception'а вы, вероятно, не увидите сообщений, т.к. System.exit экстренно завершает работу приложения. Попробуйте для начала убрать вызов этой команды и, как вариант, вывести ошибки в стандартный поток System.err? Может, исключение какое падает.

Comment: Если я убираю строчку serData, то программа идёт дальше, но важно чтобы она была...

Comment: Второй вариант - пройтись по коду в debug режиме и посмотреть, до какого места выполнение доходит и где зависает.

Comment: > Если я убираю строчку serData, то программа идёт дальше, но важно что-бы она была...

Убрать вызов команды System.exit(), не serData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `user implements Serializable`?